# Proof of Bijection

Tags: functions, relations

> Let $\def\Powerset{\mathcal P}X = \{1, 2, . . . , n\}$. Define a map on $f : \Powerset(X) \to \Powerset(X)$ as follows: for any $A ⊆ X$,
>
> Let $f(A) =\begin{cases}A \setminus\{n\} &\text{, if }& n \in A,\\ A \cup\{n\} &\text{, if }&n \notin A\end{cases}$
>
> Prove that $f$ is a bijection which maps odd subsets of $X$ onto even subsets of $X$ and vice versa (here, “odd” and “even” refers to the cardinality, i.e. number of elements, in a subset). Use this to find the number of even subsets of $X$ and the number of odd subsets of $X$.

Comment: One way to show $f$ is a bijection $P(X) \to P(X)$ is to show that the inverse $f^{-1}$ is a well-defined map $P(X) \to P(X)$ (i.e., you can write down a formula for $f^{-1}$).

Next, it should be apparent that $f$ maps odd subsets to even subsets and vice versa. Combining this fact with the fact that $f$ is a bijection should allow you to show that the number of even subsets is the same as the number of odd subsets.

Answer (score 0):

To show the bijection:

Surjectivity:

For $A\subset X,$ if $A$ contains $n,$ then $A=f(A\setminus \{n\});$ if $A$ doesn't contain $n,$ then $A=f(A\cup\{n\}).$

Invectivity:

For $A\subset X,$ if $f(A)$ contains $n,$ then $A=f(A)\setminus \{n\};$ if $f(A)$ doesn't contain $n,$ then $A=f(A)\cup\{n\}.$

Since the inverse map can be explicitly expressed and well-defined, the map is a bijection.